# How Do I create two CSS Classes and prevent line break

Tags: html, css

I have the following 2 HTML statements.  I want the "p" tag to NOT wrap to the next line. But I do want it to wrap in subsequent lines.  (so I can't use the nowrap style).  I want to create two CSS classes to treat each class differently.

```
   <b class= "mscFlapSumBold" id='flapSum0'>This is the Flap Summary</b>

   <p class= "mscFlapText" id='flap0'>This is the Flap text </p>
```

EDIT:

OK.  I'm using James suggestion and it's working except that I can't seem to change the line spacing between my lines.  When I use margin  or   line-height,  they get ignored.  So, James' suggested code is working mostly....

```
<p>
<strong class="mscFlapSumBold" id="flapSum0">...</strong>
<span class="mscFlapText" id="flap0">...</span>
</p>
```

Furthur edit:   My issue surrounds the fact that I am using jQuery Mobile. So, depending on the viewport, your solution works only sometimes (with certain viewports). Driving me CRAZY. If you have any ideas, I would sure appreciate them.

Comment: You may want to remove the margins of the p element. But actually, this is exactly what a paragraph should do. You could use `<span>` elements to format different parts of a paragraph instead.

Comment: If you insist on using paragraphs for this, set CSS display to inline.

Concerning your question about different classes treating classes differently; I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I had tried display:inline and it didn't do it for me.  Tried it again and it works just great !!!!!!!!!!   thank you!!!!!

Comment: If you use `p` and set it to `inline` you might rather be looking for `span` instead of a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap both in the same `p` element and place `.mscFlapText` within a `span` instead:

```
<p>
    <strong class="mscFlapSumBold" id="flapSum0">...</strong>
    <span class="mscFlapText" id="flap0">...</span>
</p>
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/5J7aG/).

It's worth noting that [the specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/) defines `p` as *Grouping Content* and `b` is *Text-level Semantics*; they aren't designed to go inline with each other.

Comment: James:  something wacky happening when I try to us display:inline.  Trying your suggestion now.  Thanks

Comment: James:  This seems to be working.  But, when I try to alter line spacing between the lines, it seems to override my CSS styling with default line spacing.....??

Comment: @hypermiler set your `strong` and `span` elements to display as `inline-block`.

Comment: My issue surrounds the fact that I am using jQuery Mobile.  So, depending on the viewport, your solution works only sometimes (with certain viewports).  Driving me CRAZY.  If you have any ideas, I would sure appreciate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
p.mscFlapText {
    display: inline;
}
```

But actually, you should use `<span>` instead, better not mess up with default behaviour of HTML element.

Besides that, a good habit and small tip is to use `<strong>` rather than `<b>` since it's can improve your SEO ranking.

Comment: I don't see what `strong` or `b` have to do with SEO. They're different HTML elements.